# Exiting full-screen at the end of a video with MediaElement.js

Tags: ios, safari, fullscreen, exit, mediaelement.js

When using Safari on iOS I would like the video to come out of fullscreen mode at the end of the video.

I have added the following code to the body of my page but it doesn't fire. (the alert works when un-commented). Any suggestions? Thanks

```
<script>
new MediaElement('player1', {

success: function (mediaElement, domObject) { 

// add event listener
mediaElement.addEventListener('ended', function(e) {

       //Do Stuff here
       //alert("sometext");
       $('#player1').webkitExitFullScreen();

}, false);
},
});
</script>
```

Comment: Turns out that this does work on iPad and iPhone iOS 5. I was testing with Safari on the desktop. my bad :(